# How to test async Task method

Tags: .net, unit-testing, http

How to test async Task method
My method definition:

```
class TestClient{
 public async Task SendTest(TestDto testDto, string correlationId)
 {
   await PostAsync(Routes.Test, body: testDto, correlationId: 
   correlationId).ConfigureAwait(false);
 }
}
```

The controller implementing the route:

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(201)]
[ProducesResponseType(400)]
[Route(Routes.Test)]
public async Task<IActionResult> SendEmailNotification([FromBody] TestDto 
testDto)
{
 await _testService.TestNotify(testDto);

 return StatusCode(201);
}
```

When I use the following in the test method:

```
var result = await _mockTestClient.Object.SendTest(testDto, null);
```

I get the error that  cannot assign void to an implicit type variable

Answer (score 2):

> I get the error that cannot assign void to an implicit type variable

The type returned by `SendTest` is `Task`. So the type of the expression `_mockTestClient.Object.SendTest(testDto, null)` is also `Task`.

`await` unwraps a `Task`/`Task<T>`. In the case of `Task`, there is no return type. So the type of the expression `await _mockTestClient.Object.SendTest(testDto, null)` is `void`, and you cannot assign `void` to a variable - in this case, `result`.

If you are just wanting to check for exceptions, then don't attempt to assign to the local variable:

```
await _mockTestClient.Object.SendTest(testDto, null);
```